# Why so much controversy over a little old word like "sartén"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, sustantivos, género

According to Translate.com, "the pan" is *"el sartén"*.

According to Duolingo, the object suffers from gender confusion and can be either *"el sartén"* or *"la sartén"*.

Why would it have two different genders, and why would such a basic word be a source of contention between two significant language sites?

Comment: There are other palabras ambiguas.  Internet, even tilde can be one or the other.

Comment: Aparentemente la sartén, una sarta de mentiras, y el sastre zurciendo alguna cosa comparten etimología.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RAE says:

> sartén.
>   (Del lat. sartāgo, -ĭnis).
>   1. f. Recipiente de cocina, generalmente de metal, de forma circular, poco hondo y con mango largo, que sirve para guisar. **En muchos lugares de América y España, u. c. m.**
>
> u. c. m.: [usado como masculino]

It is indeed feminine, but even when the RAE prefers this it also accepts that is masculine in some other areas.

In México you'll hear *el sartén* but the TV always says things like *Did you know that you should say* la sartén *instead of* el sartén *because the RAE says so?*.

It is important if you say *la o el* but until you discover which is the best choice in the place you are staying, I think there's no going to be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have 'two different genders', the [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/sarten) states that its gender is feminine given that it comes from the latin *sartago* which was feminine as well; however, it also states that in different parts of America and Spain, it's known as masculine, mainly because many words that end in *—én* are masculine:

> Andén, edén, almacén, etc.

If you're still doubting which one you should use, I'd advise you to go with *la sartén*. It doesn't really matter where you are, you'll be understood perfectly, people might be taken aback if they're used to *el sartén* but it shouldn't represent a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is built in social use. In Chile we say "el sartén" and "la sartén" sounds weird but we understand and accept both uses, realizing that "la" is being used by a non-Chilean speaker.

No one wonders why "el monte" (mount) is masculine and "la montaña" (mountain) is feminine. In objects, gender is a historical consequence of use, not the execution of rules.

Comment: Maybe such words should be called "hermaphrodites" or some form of that.

Comment: I think you mean "sustantivos ambiguos". I find it very odd and not really professional to call a word "hermaphrodite". However, I still believe that we should encourage the use of *la sartén* since it's in compliance with its roots.

Comment: The word _hermaphrodite_ was quoted by B. Clay Shannon. It is not problem with of professionalism. Is a metaphor.

Comment: No need to use an analogy to give a name to words that already have one, and even then, *sartén* isn't categorised as such.

Answer (score 2):

According to RAE [sartén is feminine](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=MBLAvOoXaDXX2UIEflMV), so it is *always* **la sartén** and never "el sartén".

I can confirm you that none of these words have two genders. I have never heard "el sartén". I think that duolingo in this case is not to be trusted.

Comment: Diego, you should check out the clarification made by the RAE at the end of the first definition.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean? Could you give me an example where *pan* is referred as feminine?

Comment: I was talking about *sartén*.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean? Could you give me an example where _sartén_ is referred as masculine?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el+sart%C3%A9n%2C+la+sart%C3%A9n&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cel%20sart%C3%A9n%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20sart%C3%A9n%3B%2Cc0 Take a look. Though the usage of *la sartén* is way more common, *el sartén* is used as well. You can always look up books that contain the word *el sartén* and you'll find many of these are for food recipes.

Comment: @Diego in the RAE, the last bit of the first definition says "u. c. m" "usado como masculino"

Comment: @Diego as a native spanish speaker I can tell you that I use "El sartén" , I do have heard "La sartén" and I agree with Jerson and Rodrigo that EL/La,for this particular case, depends on the country

Comment: OK, I learnt something new today. I guess that this might be one of those times that the RAE accepts an a use that "doesn't follow the rules" because is getting more extensively used. Thanks all.

Comment: Tienes q tener en cuenta q el rae es muy lento actualizandose, y la gebte evoluciona mas rapido.

Comment: @EmilioGort, no sé si el RAE es lento o simplemente termina por claudicar, como en el tuit-broma de [_alomojó_](http://www.tagthebird.com/es/tweets/659901):

Comment: Si creo q es lento, he estado en muchos paises de habla hispana, y son un mundo distinto cada uno. Escribo desde el cel.

Comment: Y en cuba se usa 'la sarten'