# Why is this sentence attaching el?

Tags: artículos

I found:

> Nosotros leemos el diario.

Newspapers are not men and women. Why is this sentence attaching `el`?

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! See [this answer](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16310/12637), I think it will solve your question. Bear in mind that Spanish words have a _género_ but not a _gender_ (_sex_). Words like "el" or "la" just mean "the" in English,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*El* in this sentence is an article, the one ur messing up with is the pronoun.

The article has 4 forms, it depends if the noun is masculine, feminine and singular or plural.

Its like in English *We read the newspaper*, and **diario** is masculine and singular.

Answer (score 1):

After I searched why, I found. Because:

- Spanish has **masculine noun** and **feminine noun**.
- Newspapers are masculine noun.
- Even if it do not has gender, noun has masculine noun and feminine noun.